# Install unixodbc-dev for a Flask web app on Azure App Service

Tags: python, azure, flask, pyodbc, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to deploy Flask web app on the Azure App Service. This app is using pyodbc to connect to mssql; however, when I deploy the app I get this error

> ImportError: libodbc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such
>   file or directory

I got to know that I can solve this issue by installing unixodbc/unixodbc-dev with the following line:

```
sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev
```

I tried to do this manually by accessing the SSH of Kudu; however, the issue still persists.

I am using a local repository and pushing the code with git to Azure. When I get this error, I can't access the console from Kudu, so I had to comment the code and push again. Then I tried to install this package manually by doing apt-get install unixodbc-dev (because sudo is not recognized) and it works well. Then I pushed the code again with pyodbc on it and the same error is showing. I think the packages are being erased each time I do that since I found some of the folders created by this packages being deleted after the push action.

The error I always get is as follow:

[image: Lines from the Log Stream]

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, you were using Azure WebApp for Linux which be based on Docker. So any changes you did in a container just be writen in the `container layer` which will be deleted when a contaner is deleted (includes stop/restart operation), as the offical Docker document [About images, containers, and storage drivers](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/storagedriver/imagesandcontainers/) said as below.

> **Images and layers**
>
> When you create a new container, you add a new writable layer on top of the underlying layers. This layer is often called the **"container layer"**. All changes made to the running container, such as writing new files, modifying existing files, and deleting files, are written to this thin writable container layer.
>
> **Container and layers**
>
> The major difference between a container and an image is the top writable layer. All writes to the container that add new or modify existing data are stored in this writable layer. **When the container is deleted, the writable layer is also deleted.** The underlying image remains unchanged.

Therefore, if you want to save your changes in your running container, you must to commit these changes to create a new image via command [`docker commit`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/). Or in your scenario for installing the required packages, you can follow the Azure documents [`SSH support for Azure App Service on Linux`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-ssh-support) and [`Use a custom Docker image for Web App for Containers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-custom-docker-image) to add these commands as below into your Dockerfile to create a image to push and deploy it to Azure WebApp for Linux.

```
# Add unixodbc support
RUN apt-get update \
        && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends unixodbc-dev
```