# Not able to download pyodbc to Azure App Service

Tags: python, azure, flask, sqlalchemy, azure-sql-database

I'm using Azure App Service to make my website. The website worked fine on my localhost, using a sqllite database and SQLAlchemy. Now I am trying to switch to the Azure SQL DB using this: https://gist.github.com/timmyreilly/f4a351eda5dd45aa9d56411d27573d7c

I followed the directions, but I'm getting this error. I looked up the error and found this: [pyodbc - error while running application within a container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43417886/pyodbc-error-while-running-application-within-a-container) but it wasn't able to help because the solution there said to do `sudo apt install unixodbc-dev`, but Azure CLI doesn't let me use sudo so I'm not sure how I can do this. Can you guys help me, what should I do?

```
2019-02-15T00:55:28.174067202Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/connectors/pyodbc.py", line 38, in dbapi
2019-02-15T00:55:28.174070902Z     return __import__('pyodbc')
2019-02-15T00:55:28.174195702Z ImportError: libodbc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: How do you deploy your app to azure? following this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-python)?

Comment: @IvanYang Yes, thats what i used

Comment: Have you try creating a virtual environment for your python project, before publish to azure?

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: You can follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-python#run-the-app-locally), and remember add the pyodbc and  it's version in the requirements.txt.

Comment: @IvanYang oh yeah i have a virtual env for my python project but its not on azure only the requirements.txt is on azure

Answer (score 0):

According to your error information and the @IvanYang comments, you deployed your Python app on Azure App Service for Linux Container which be based on Docker.

So you can refer to the offical document [`SSH support for Azure App Service on Linux`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-ssh-support) to connect to the Linux system of your app to install the missing `unixodbc-dev` package via `sudo apt install unixodbc-dev` and then to make your app works before restart your app service.

The change of `unixodbc-dev` installed is temporary for docker container, you can refer to the existing SO thread [Install unixodbc-dev for a Flask web app on Azure App Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54002014/install-unixodbc-dev-for-a-flask-web-app-on-azure-app-service/54230534#54230534) to know it. The only way to keep it works is to add the content below into your `.dockerfile` file or to use a docker image which had been installed the required packages when create an App Service instance on Linux.

```
# Add unixodbc support
RUN apt-get update \
        && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends unixodbc-dev
```

Comment: Where is my .dockerfile?

Comment: Sorry I'm really new at this

Comment: Hey, if you're there to help that would be great I'm still struggling on this.

Comment: @SheshankS. Please see the tutorial for using a custom Docker image ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-custom-docker-image))